# How do I prevent followers from blocking doorways?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I feel great affection for Lydia.  She has been a stalwart companion almost from the beginning.  Fighting at my side, watching my back, and even sharing my burdens.  And she has done it all with no complaint.  And no more sarcasm than is justified.

She *does* have a few bad habits… charging headlong at dragons, for instance.  Refusing to break off an attack until the foe is slain.  Wandering between me and the bandit I'm trying to incinerate.

*Standing in doorways like an unassailable bastion.*

So… when dear Lydia has taken it upon herself to confine me to a room by standing in the doorway, how might I convince her to budge?

Comment: You: FUS RO DAH!

Comment: I like you @Raven :P

Comment: A more friendly option: WULD NAH KEST!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just sprint into her, you will push her back; the default key on PC is <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Alternatively, cast the Whirlwind Sprint...

Comment: or you just FUS RO DAH them out of the way ;)

Comment: A great way to interrupt the blabbering of annoying NPCs in town as well :)

Answer (score 35):

Most of the time, walking or sprinting into a follower will make them move. However, there have been occasions where no matter how much I ran into Lydia, she wouldn't budge. In that case, there is a simple solution. Just talk to her and select the "I want you to do something" option. You can then point at a location to tell her to move there, which should get her out of your way.

Comment: A little hard to use, but undeniably effective!

Comment: Or you can hold 'E' to get into 'command mode' easily

Answer (score 8):

For some reason, I've found that crouching (sneaking) consistently gets her out of my way.  When I crouch, she crouches too and seems to shift her position just enough to let me get by.

Answer (score 7):

As with any question about annoyances in gameplay on a Bethesda game, this question can be answered with "There's a mod for that."  Several, in fact.  Not even bothering with the multiple-follower overhauls that tweak the entire follower AI, I present the two mods that actually address exactly this issue:

- [**Move it Dammit**](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/4020) tweaks the sensitivity of the normal AI's politeness.  Rather than having to stand in their face for a few seconds before they decide to move aside, they'll get out of your way much faster.  If you're walking, you might not even have to stop for an entire group of followers in a doorway.
- [**Get Out Of My Way!**](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/30092) lets you use dialog to stagger or knock down people who might otherwise ignore being staggered.  It's also fun for just pushing people around because you're saving the whole freaking world and they aren't giving you the respect that deserves.

Answer (score 2):

I walk to any corner of the room and she follows. Then I walk by the door.

Answer (score 2):

I found walking into her and jumping up and down repeatedly as I continue to walk forward makes her back off.

Answer (score 2):

For your main companion, you can talk to them, select "I need you to do something," and tell them to wait in a specific spot, then point the crosshair where you want them to move. Clunky, but easy enough.

It's local NPCs, children/spouses, and non-commandable followers like that talking dog that really cause trouble. With the "Pets of Skyrim," you can use the Teleport Pet spells to relocate your pet, or just tell them to go home to start them walking away and then immediately say "Follow me" to them when you've gotten out of whatever corner you were stuck in.

When you're doing stuff around your player home, I honestly think it saves a lot of hassle to tell both your pet and your follower to "Wait here" someplace unobtrusive and out-of-the-way, like a rarely-visited corner of the place.

Answer (score 1):

If she's standing in a doorway with a closable door, try closing and opening the door.  That will often push her out of the way, in one direction or another depending on where exactly she's standing.

Answer (score 0):

I always hit her until she stops following and goes away, then I ask her to follow me again.