# Is there a mod or console command which will allow me to push followers out of the way?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Right, so I read the similar question and the answers were pretty much everything I've done to get past them. What I want to know is if there is a console command or mod or something else that lets you push these nefarious followers out of your way. By followers I mean everything: followers, thralls, dogs, atronachs, etc.

To emphasize: I'm aware of ways to make them to move somewhere specific, what I want is a way to enable me to **push** them out of the way or move **through** them or otherwise keep them entirely out of the way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent followers from blocking doorways?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/how-do-i-prevent-followers-from-blocking-doorways)

Comment: yes i am asking the same question that ben asked however im not looking for one of the many justpushintothemuntiltheymove fixes im looking for a console command or mod that makes it so i can push them out of the way by walking into them or something. thralls do not move out of the way when you walk into them. i want to be able to have thralls without the annoyance of having to kill them as soon as i enter a dead end.

Comment: Can I suggest that you try to avoid too many reallylongwordsthatarereallylongfornorealreason? They make the question harder to read and don't really add anything.

Comment: because im not fond of forums, and dont use them often.  i dont like deleting things ive said because i usually forget what ive said hence the spam edits. also lol, completely rewrote what i said.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the mod you're looking for:

#### [Move it Dammit!](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/4020)

[image: Move it Dammit! image]

> **Cause:**
> If Companions or Creatures are in a doorway, sometimes they don't move
> far enough and continue to block your way..
>
> **Resolve:**
> This esp will tell them to walk around double the distance away from
> you rather than default values.  If there is no way forward they will
> walk around you in a circle, so ensure there's room for them.

*Move it Dammit!* also has a 'Less Wait Time' version, that should make the follower move almost instantly upon bumping them.

Also, try its optional add-on:

**Stop Bumping into Me!**

> Keeps your Companions and Creatures at a more managable Distance while still keeping up for Battle detection.
> also from running - walk - stop is more immediate...

Comment: well, its better than the ones i could find. still, it doesnt account for the atronarchs who still simply stand(or float) and laugh at me.

Comment: @BelamAshborne It works fine for me, even with creature followers (like atronarchs and reanimated Draugrs). However, you might want to report that issue at the [Move it Dammit! forum thread](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?showtopic=501179).

Comment: huh. that is odd. maybe my game's just glitched then, atronachs have never moved out of the way for me, always had to kill/lead them out of the doorways/corridors. will have to look it up.

Answer (score 2):

If you stand still nose-to-nose with them for a second, they will step back a bit. Took me 2 playthroughs to figure out.

If you want to move through them, use TCL (make sure you don't have a target selected, or they will become bugged).

You can also FUSRODAH them out of the way, it's not a crime. Works on flame atronachs, sort of stumbles frost atronachs uselessly and makes storm atronachs swirl.

Comment: oh hey woops tried editing the answer as a form of response o-o;;; did not see the add comment box i swear. i forget what i said but tcl is cool but its like trading one annoyance for another. and yeah i know the standfacetoface trick as well as murdering the dumb sod. which is what i usually do to my atronachs.

Comment: does unrelenting force work on atronachs? i never tried it on them lol oh also i wouldnt do it since i may accidently send them flying off a mountain or something o-o im a clumsy oaf lol

Comment: Because every atronach is a precious, special snowflake. Updated the answer.

Comment: i dont enjoy the internet sarcasm, no theyre not but the time i waste summoning then killing them out of my way then summoning them again is.

Comment: And how often do you expect to be stuck in a door atop a mountain?

Comment: it was an example, it could be inside a cave with them on a bridge over doom. fusrodah, they fall to their death when i didnt mean to kill them etc.

Comment: That still doesn't happen.

Comment: \o/ whatever its not that helpful and id manage to kill my human person somehow.

Comment: @kotekzot "*If you want to move through them, use TCL (make sure you don't have a target selected, or they will become bugged).*" Has this been confirmed? I have accidentally TCL'ed when I had something selected multiple times. What bugs am I to expect if I TCL'ed an NPC or a background object?

Comment: @galacticninja I saw an NPC I accidentally TLD'd "fly" in the air to attack a dragon. I decided to make double sure not to let something like that happen again and left it at that. Don't know about static objects, perhaps they will become pass-through.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting mod named **[Come together N Out of the way — Nausicaa-S Tweaker](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/33562)** (link for Nexus Mods) allowing more complex settings and possibly the best way to get rid of problems with this issue:

> If your followers are blocking your way, you can move them using very
>   simple menu controls. Also, if the distance of your followers is too
>   far from you, you can make them come closer using the same menu. You
>   can move NPCs to your front or their original location. You can be
>   moved to a selected NPC. Also, you can resurrect dead NPCs. And more
>   useful things.

[image: screenshot]